# Show badge or version number on gitlab-ci pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In Gitlab-ci, each of my pipelines creates a version number. I want to show that version number for each pipeline run on the pipeline page. Anybody know of a way to do it? I'm showing it as a badge on the Overview page but I want it on the pipeline page as well.